# Elegant way of parsing non-JSON strings into object / dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, parsing

I'm working on an app that requires a lot of custom parsers. I have been able to parse the strings into objects fine using Swift String methods but it feels rather bulky and slow.

Here is an example - parsing the result of the FTP MLSD command:

```
let test = "size=3919312;type=file;perm=r;modify=20000310140400; bar.txt"

struct FTPResource {
    var size: UInt64
    var type: FileType
    var permission: Permission
    var modified: Date
    var name: String

    init() {
        size = 0
        type = .file
        permission = .r
        modified = Date()
        name = ""
    }
}

enum Attribute: String {
    case size
    case type
    case perm
    case modify
}

enum FileType: String {
    case file
    case dir
}

enum Permission: String {
    case r
    case rw
}

func parseMLSD(data: String) -> FTPResource {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let array = data.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").components(separatedBy: ";")

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"

    var ftpObject = FTPResource()

    for item in array {
        let attribute = item.components(separatedBy: "=")
        switch Attribute(rawValue: attribute[0]) {
        case .size?:
            ftpObject.size = UInt64(attribute[1])!
            break
        case .type?:
            ftpObject.type = FileType(rawValue: attribute[1])!
            break
        case .perm?:
            ftpObject.permission = Permission(rawValue: attribute[1])!
            break
        case .modify?:
            print(attribute[1])
            ftpObject.modified = dateFormatter.date(from: attribute[1])!
            break
        default:
            ftpObject.name = attribute[0]
            break
        }
    }

    return ftpObject
}

print(parseMLSD(data: test))
```

I've looked around the web for better, more compact solutions to this but almost all of them expect a JSON type string. Is there a better way to achieve this in Swift?

(Note - I am aware that force unwrapping the optionals in the switch statement isn't a good idea but I'm just using this as an example.)

Comment: Well if you are using a custom format, you obviously won't be able to use an existing parser that works with formats that are publicly used. The only way you might be able to make your own parser any better is by using regular expressions.

Comment: Oh I understand - it's just frustrating that if you Google "Swift parse string into object" the results always relate to JSON. I'd be happy to use regex assuming it's faster / cleaner than what I've have above.

Comment: Since JSON is the most widely used string format nowadays, it isn't so surprising... Your format is quite straightforward, so even a regex might not help that much, but you should give it a try and see if you get cleaner code.

Comment: Just a general comment on your code: in Swift you don't need to use `break`s inside your switch cases, they are not cascading.

Comment: My bad - I added the breaks to suppress error messages while coming up with the content for each case and forgot to removed them.